# web-scraping with jquery ajax error {“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping

I want to scrape a web which loads it's data via ajax call. when I inspect it and get the all parameters, I call it with ajax and get error like this:
`{“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}`. I was digging on the Internet and found some issues. 1- id cross domain, 2- ajax request dons't run completely. here is my code:
thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var url='http://www.festivalsandeventsontario.ca/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
var query_args=[];
var data={
    query_args:[
        {'cat':42,'posts_per_page':42,'order':'ASC','meta_key':'feo_member','meta_value':'True','filter':'filter_where'}
    ],
    action:"retrieve_posts",
    page_number: 4,
    filter: 'filter_where',
    user_function: 'the_event_item'
};

$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    //dataType:'json',
    success: function(result){
        //var t=JSON.stringify(result);
        //$('#tab1').html(JSON.parse(t));
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

Comment: If the remote domain doesn't have CORS enabled, there's nothing you can do with XHR. You'll have to make your own server-side implementation, and have your JS call that.

Comment: are you [john john](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120357/how-to-assign-value-of-an-array-inside-an-object-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment65590443_39120357)

Comment: @Scott. what do you mean by saying "you'll have to make your own server-side implementation. you mean to say there is no way to cope with the problem

Comment: Not on the client-side.  I meant you'd do the same request from your actual server, and expose that request to your front-end.  For example, you'd make a request to your local domain (localhost) which goes off to download festivalsandevents, then return that response.